# Java can't find symbol from .class in the same directory

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, symbols

I have two files: MyStringLog.java (which extends ArrayStringLog) and TestDriver.java in the same directory. Why doesn't TestDriver.java recognize the MyStringLog constructor from the MyStringLog class? In TestDriver.java I declare:

```
MyStringLog animals = new MyStringLog("animals");
```

This is supposed to construct a new MyStringLog object named animals, but I get 2 errors when I compile, both, that MyStringLog symbol is not found.

- ArrayStringLog.java: http://pastebin.com/Z624DRcm
- MyStringLog.java:http://pastebin.com/zaH2S3yg
- TestDriver.java:

  ```
  public class TestDriver {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          MyStringLog animals = new MyStringLog("animals");
          animals.insert("dog");
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: are you importing `MyStringLog` with an import statement?

Comment: I think you need to add this current directory to the class path. something like adding "-cp ." to the command line.

Comment: You say they're in the same directory, but do they have the same package?

Comment: You were right Nicolas. By appending :. to the end of my CLASSPATH declaration all my problems went away. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to roughly work. To do so...

for the file `ArrayStringLog.java`, I removed the `implements StringLogInterface` because I simply don't have access to that interface. After doing so, I removed the `package ch02.stringLogs;`. When I compiled this file with the `package...` still there, I recieved the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ArrayStringLog (wrong name: ch02/stringLogs/ArrayStringLog)`

Then in `MyStringLog.java`, I removed the `import ch02.stringLogs.*;`. I then saved and compiled the code, and ran the TestDriver, to which I received no compilation errors.

This leads me to believe that your error stems from the `package` statement in `ArrayStringLog.java`.

---

To finally get a compilation, I put all four files (ArrayStringLog, MyStringLog, StringLogInterface, TestDriver) into the same directory, removed any `package...` statements, **added back `implements StringLogInterface`** to ArrayStringLog.java, compiled each one, and then ran TestDriver with an added `toString` method from which the output was:

```
Log: animals

1. dog
2. cat
```

Here was the test driver:

```
public class TestDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStringLog animals = new MyStringLog("animals");
        animals.insert("dog");
        animals.insert("cat");

        System.out.println(animals.toString());
    }
}
```

To make clear, ArrayStringLog begins with:

```
public class ArrayStringLog implements StringLogInterface
```

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo posting it here. My file there is no typo.

Comment: Note, the above comment was in response to my previous answer and no longer applies.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6koo8eim16xcskb/bookFiles.zip these are all the files we're using. I looked at a classmate's code which compiled and they didn't have to touch ArrayStringLog.java.

Comment: See my revised answer. If you have more questions, comment away.

Comment: I removed "implements StringLogInterface" from ArrayStringLog.java. I removed "package ch02.stringLogs;" from all files. I placed them all in the same directory, but MyStringLog.java won't compile and neither will TestDriver.java. Did I forget to remove something?

Comment: How about now (see the bolded edit)? I think I miscommunicated a bit. My fault.

Comment: I got it to work by opening a new Terminal which reset $CLASSPATH. Thanks for all of your awesome help.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `import MyStringLog;` to your file.

Also are you using packages? In which case it should be `import <package_name>.MyStringLog;`

Comment: This gives me the error "TestDriver.java:1: error: '.' expected import MyStringLog;" with the arrow pointing to the semicolon. The ArrayStringLog class is in the ch02.stringLogs package, which MyStringLog.java imports.

Comment: use `import ch02.stringLogs.MyStringLog;` then